# weird grey square in extjs layout (ie7 & 8 only)

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-7

I have weird grey square in extjs layout (ie7 & 8 only).

I applyed css code to  all doc in hope to see borders of gray element but...
There are NO BORDER ON IT. please tell me what to do or check next.

```
*{
border:1px red solid !important;
}
```

**ie7 & ie 8**

[image: ie7 & ie 8]

**normal browser**
[image: normal browser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like IE isn't rendering things correctly. Something was at that position and when the form was rendered, IE didn't keep up with the redraw.

Comment: it looks like non- DOM element. otherwise it would have border:1px red solid